# How to eliminate double surname from counting in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data with household and customers. In one household it can be more than one customer with different surnames. If there is husband (smith) and wife with duoble surname (jones-smith) it's not a problem. I want only completely different surnames.
How to count the customers in household with different surnames?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and the query you are now using.  Without context, your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: What's wrong with `COUNT(DISTINCT Surname)`?

Comment: Distinct is not the answer because smith and jones-smith are technically different but still first surname is included in the second one (there are marriage and can be count as one). My goal is to count how many not related surnames is in household.

Comment: That is the opposite of what you say you in your question, @Daria *"If there is husband (smith) and wife with duoble surname (jones-smith) it's not a problem."* So it's not a problem, as they are different

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain well, what I meant it is not a problem for my case, problem is when I have completely different people in one household.

Answer (score 0):

If you add sample data, we can help you more easily. You can probably solve your problem with the LIKE operator. I think it can be solved with `LIKE '%smith%'`.